# Index out of range exception in datagridview when header is selected

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that when I click on a header to sort or for any reason I get the follow error on the following line of code....

**Argument our of range exception (Index was out of range.  Must be non negative and less than the size of the collection.**

```
 private void firearmView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            //I get the above error on the IF line below.
            if (!firearmView.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) 
            {
                selectedFirearmPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(firearmView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString(), true);
            }

    }
```

I do not know why I am getting this particular error here.

Comment: I suspect `Cells[12]`. How many cells are there on a row?

Comment: 14 for this table if starting with 0.  Cell 12 is where the Photo path is located.  That is how I am populating picture boxes.

Comment: No problem, then I suspect @Steve has the answer!

Comment: I don't know if perhaps this may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280837/getting-index-was-out-of-range-exception-in-datagridview-when-clicking-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN says in the docs about [RowIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When the RowIndex property returns -1, the cell is either a column
>   header, or the cell's row is shared.

So you need to handle the e.RowIndex == -1 when you receive the event
(...The index must not be negative....)

```
private void firearmView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.RowIndex == -1) return;

    if (!firearmView.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) 
    {
        selectedFirearmPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(firearmView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, this is spot on.  Caused another issue though, probably my fault.  However, for others I will post a new question.  Thanks again.