# Getting "Index was out of range" exception in DataGridView when clicking header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, indexoutofrangeexception

I am using a DataGridView to display my data from a SQLite database. One column is a directory to open pdfs assigned to the row. The code works but, every time I click on the column title, it gives me the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Actually, any time I click the column text (just "PDF", or any other column's text) it throws that error. But when I click outside the text (anywhere in the ordering box), it reorders my columns, which is ok. Any ideas?

The code works, opens up the PDF, but I don't want the user accidentally clicking the title text and the program crash. Here is the code for the datagridview to open the pdf.

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Process.Start(filename);
        } 
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting the exception when you click the header because the `RowIndex` is `-1`. You don't want anything to happen when they click the header anyway, so you can check for that value and ignore it.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex != 3)  // ignore header row and any column
        return;                                  //  that doesn't have a file name

    var filename = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

    if (File.Exists(filename))
        Process.Start(filename);
}
```

Also, FWIW, you're only getting the exception when you click the text in the header because you subscribed to `CellContentClick` (only fires when you click the content of the cell, such as the text). I'd suggest using the `CellClick` event (fires when any part of the cell is clicked).

Comment: thanks! i knew i had to change the rowIndex to -1 but i was using && instead of || in a similar way you wrote your code when i was testing other ways. THANKS! worked like a charm!